# source not found when creating object

Tags: java, android

I want to have a method in the class *GolferDBManager* return an array of objects that I am constructing from an SQLLite db. I am getting a *Source Not Found* error in the method when I try to build the array.

```
    public Golfer[] retrieveGolfers(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{"golfer_name", "golfer_init", "usga_index"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        Golfer tGolfer = new Golfer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2));
        lGolfers[i] = new Golfer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }  
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return lGolfers;
}
```

*lGolfers* is defined above in the class definitions as:

```
public class GolferDBManager {
 public static final String DB_NAME = "golfgames";
 public static final String DB_TABLE = "golfers";
 public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, golfer_name TEXT, golfer_init TEXT, usga_index DOUBLE);";
 private SQLHelper helper;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;
 private Context context;
 private Golfer lGolfers[];
```

The

```
Golfer tGolfer = new Golfer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2));
```

line works fine. I added it for debug purposes. The next line generates the *Source Not Found* error. I know the constructor for the class Golfer is there because I just used in the previous line.

Here is the code that calls all of this:

```
    public class ReadGolfers extends Activity {
    public Golfer Golfers[];
    private GolferDBManager mydManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_golfers);

        mydManager = new GolferDBManager(this);
        mydManager.openReadable();
        Golfers = mydManager.retrieveGolfers();
        mydManager.retrieveGolfers();
        mydManager.close();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?

Thanks.

As an afterthought, I changed the method to have the object array passed to it as follows:

```
    public void retrieveGolfers(Golfer lgolfers[]){
    String[] columns = new String[]{"golfer_name", "golfer_init", "usga_index"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        lgolfers[i] = new Golfer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }  
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Still no joy.

Comment: Where do you initialize the lGolfers[] array?

Comment: It is up there in the definition of the GolferDBManager class.

Comment: That's the declaration.  Where do you do the 'new' thing to instantiate it?

Comment: Right in the line that says: lGolfers[i] = new Golfer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2));

Comment: I also tried instantiating it in the calling routine (Golfers = null)- just before the call. No difference.

Comment: I think I finally figured it out...Rick, you gave me the clue. I did not realize that arrays in Java must be of a fixed length. I thought that repeated 'new' things were growing a variable-length array. Seems like a waste of space to have to allocate ma-length arrays, but this seems to get me past my current roadblock. Thanks.

Comment: Ah so!  I missed it, but was wondering why you were using a fixed size array instead of a collection.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Oh wait.  I did see that line.  You are adding an item to the array there, not initializing the array itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this whole line is wrong:

```
private Golfer lGolfers[];
```

It should be:

```
private Golfer[] lGolfers;
```

And initialized with:

```
lGolfers = new Golfer[100];
```

(or whatever size you wanted)

Much better is to use an ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Golfer> lGolfers = new ArrayList<Golfer>();
```